# Automating emails on Google sheets

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to automate sending emails on Google sheets using Mailapp.
My problem is the following:

I need to include the gmail signature in the email.

When using Mailapp, the pre-defined signature on gmail does not appear.
Is there any solution for that?

The other solution, as I found online, is using HTML.
I need to develop the email automation for many users on a single google sheet and need to include Linkedin links.
My issue here is that I am not able to assign HTML's 'href' as a variable (variable that is in fact a cell containing the linkedin link.

JS:

```
var linkedin_link = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1).getValue();
var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("MailTemplate");
var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();
MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "xxx@gmail.com",
        subject: "Automation",
        htmlBody: message,
        });
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="https://linkedin.com/" + linkedin_link >LINKEDIN</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

If anyone could help it would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you enable Gmail advance API (under services) you can use this to get the signature as HTML. Then you can use this in your own html template:

```
function readCurrentOutOfOffice(){
  console.log(Gmail.Users.Settings.getVacation('user@company.com'))
}
```